# Android Studio-unused import-com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

Tags: android, android-studio

Just now i started using Android studio and i imported one app from my eclipse workspace to android studio.The problem arose when tried to run the app.The error was unused import-import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
I have searched internet and couldn't find a good solution.Please help.

Comment: Does it say which file the import is in?

Comment: No Sir,   Only error displaying as if it could not find that particular import.

Comment: This is how the dependencies in build.gradle looks like

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}

Comment: From some internet researching i found that GCMBaseIntentService is deprecated.So should I go for another option in android studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GCMBaseIntentService is deprecated. You need to use GoogleCloudMessaging API instead. Please refer the following link to get the implementation of the API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html

Comment: Is there any way / documentation that can be referred to migrate the class. As I can see there are lots of changes and many methods are not available